# NODE.JS 'request' not adding response in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

So I'm trying to webscrape data of steam community market. And it works for a small amount of items, but when I try for CS:GO (avg: 13400 items) it doesn't. I use Steam's JSON which allows me to get 100 items at a time. The code does the following: inside the loop it gets a random pause (I know ugly way to pause with that while, but another way froze my loop), then I send the first request. I check if I got a response and if my response code was 200 (= success) then I get each item out of the json array and check if it is already in my array or not, if not I add it.

But here lies the problem. It seems to do all the request loops, and then at the end of that it seems to do all the item adding to the array. Instead of doing a request, add the item and then start a new request and continue.

```
const colors = require('colors/safe');
const request = require('request');
const random = require('random');
var fs = require('fs');

var itemNames = new Array();

console.log(colors.green(time() + 'Starting Steam Market Monitor...'));

request('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&start=0&count=100', function(err, res, body) {
    if (res.statusCode == 200 && res.statusCode != undefined) {
    var itemsObj = JSON.parse(body);
    var totalItems = itemsObj['total_count'];
    console.log(colors.green(time() + 'Total of items found: ' + totalItems));
    getItems(totalItems);
    } else {
        console.log(colors.red(time() + 'Response code: ' + res.statusCode));
    }
});

function getItems(totalItems) {
    var status = 200; //default success message
    console.log(colors.green(time() + "Started item grabbing."));


    for (var i = 0; i < totalItems; i+= 100) {

        var options = {
            url: 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&start='+ i +'&count=100'
        };

        var dt = new Date();
        var randomSeconds = random.int(115, 125);
        dt.setSeconds( dt.getSeconds() + randomSeconds );
        while(dt > new Date()) {}
            console.log(colors.green(time() + "Getting items " + i + " out of " + totalItems + " items"));
                var dt = new Date();
                var randomSeconds = random.int(55, 65);
                dt.setSeconds( dt.getSeconds() + randomSeconds );
                while(dt > new Date()) {}
                request(options, function(err, res, body) {
                    if(res) {
                        if (res.statusCode == 200 && res.statusCode != undefined) {
                            var itemsObj = JSON.parse(body);
                            var itemsArr = itemsObj['results'];

                            for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                                var item = itemsArr[j]['hash_name'];
                                if (itemNames.indexOf(item) > -1) {
                                    if (j == 99) {
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    console.log(item);
                                    itemNames.push(item);
                                    if (j == 99) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log(colors.red(time() + 'Response code: ' + res.statusCode));
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log(colors.red(time() + 'Undefined response...'));
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) package instead so you can run you requests in async way, so your loop will wait until the request end

So your code could be improved in this way:

```
const colors = require('colors/safe');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const random = require('random');
var fs = require('fs');

var itemNames = new Array();

console.log(colors.green(time() + 'Starting Steam Market Monitor...'));

rp('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&start=0&count=100',)
.then(function (res) {
    if (res.statusCode == 200 && res.statusCode != undefined) {
    var itemsObj = JSON.parse(body);
    var totalItems = itemsObj['total_count'];
    console.log(colors.green(time() + 'Total of items found: ' + totalItems));
    await getItems(totalItems);
    } else {
        console.log(colors.red(time() + 'Response code: ' + res.statusCode));
    }
})
.catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

async function getItems(totalItems) {
    var status = 200; //default success message
    console.log(colors.green(time() + "Started item grabbing."));


    for (var i = 0; i < totalItems; i+= 100) {

        var options = {
            uri: 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&start='+ i +'&count=100'
        };

            console.log(colors.green(time() + "Getting items " + i + " out of " + totalItems + " items"));
                await rp(options)
               .then(function (res) {
                    if(res) {
                        if (res.statusCode == 200 && res.statusCode != undefined) {
                            var itemsObj = JSON.parse(body);
                            var itemsArr = itemsObj['results'];

                            for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                                var item = itemsArr[j]['hash_name'];
                                if (itemNames.indexOf(item) > -1) {
                                    if (j == 99) {
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    console.log(item);
                                    itemNames.push(item);
                                    if (j == 99) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log(colors.red(time() + 'Response code: ' + res.statusCode));
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log(colors.red(time() + 'Undefined response...'));
                    }
                }).catch(function (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a little bit, ass for example I didn't get the statusCode (fixed that now) and some minor errors, but still managed to fix it using your solution. Thank you very much!